# Shiny Dashboard Empty box size

Tags: shiny, box, shinydashboard

I am developing shiny app with dashboard. Before data is entered I have nice phrases with warnings but they are appearing outside boxes or on edges like on picture below. I have no idea what to do.

I tried creating empty spaces in boxes like here:

```
box(width=12,
    tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Count matrix",
            h4(""),
            DT::dataTableOutput("dataRaw"))))
```

Text is an output from:

```
dataRaw <- reactive({
    validate(need(input$countMatrix != 0, "To perform analysis, please select an input file")))
```

The problem is:

[image]

Comment: u spelled preview wrong!

Comment: You may be able to go ahead and create an empty ggplot object (or whichever plot you are using) so that it displays a blank plain when validate is false.

Comment: You can use css to adjust the height of the tabPanel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a minimal example of what you want to achieve. 
Here `tags$head(tags$style(HTML(".tab-pane { height: 70vh; overflow-y: auto; }" )))` sets the height of tab panel to occupy 70% of the screen.

```
     library(shiny)
     library(shinydashboard)


     ui <- dashboardPage(
       dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
       dashboardSidebar(),
       dashboardBody(
         box(width=12,
             tags$head(tags$style(HTML(".tab-pane { height: 70vh; overflow-y: auto; }" ))),
             tabsetPanel(
               tabPanel("Count matrix",
                        h4(""),
                        DT::dataTableOutput("dataRaw"))))

       )
     )

     server <- function(input, output) {
       dataRaw <- reactive({
         validate(need(input$countMatrix != 0, "To perform analysis, please select an input file"))
       })

       output$dataRaw <- DT::renderDataTable(dataRaw())
     }

     shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Using the above code you get something like this:

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: Could you accept the answer if your question has been addressed?